$a$ non-nilpotent element of $R$ and $S=\{a,a^2,a^3, \dots\}$; show that $P$ is prime ideal

Let $a$ be a non-nilpotent element of $R$ and $S=\{a,a^2,a^3, \dots\}$.If $P$ is the maximal element of the family of all ideals disjoint from $S$; then $P$ is a prime ideal.

I'm not sure about this result for a non-commutative ring $R$; however, if we considered that $R$ is commutative:
BWOC, suppose that $ xy \in P$ but $x \notin P, \;  y \notin P$.
Now, we should have that $(x) \cap S; (y) \cap S \neq \emptyset$ as $P$ is the maximal ideal with the property that $P \cap S=\emptyset$.
$$rx=a^k \quad sy=a^l$$ for some $r,s \in R$ and $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
As $xy \in P$, $\quad r(xy)s \in P \implies a^{k+l} \in P \implies S \cap P \neq \emptyset\;$ $(\ast)$
Any suggestions to solve for the case of $R$ being non-commutative in the case of being still valid?

This is the "right" set of definitions for noncommutative rings.

A proper ideal $P$ of a ring $R$ is called prime if $aRb\subseteq P$ implies $a\in P$ or $b\in P$.

A nonempty subset $M$ of $R$ is called an $m$-system of $R$ if, for any two elements, $a,b\in M$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $arb\in M$.

Theorem: If $M$ is an $m$-system in a ring $R$, an ideal of $R$ which is maximal with respect to being disjoint from $M$ is a prime ideal.


The powers of an element do comprise an $m$-system, and if the element is not nilpotent then at least the ideal $\{0\}$ is disjoint from the collection of powers.  By Zorn there exists an ideal maximal w.r.t. being disjoint from the powers, and it must be prime in the sense I have given.
But one cannot be certain the ideal is prime using the "commutative definition."  Ideals which satisfy that definition are called "completely prime" in noncommutative literature.
Here is a concrete example of why the resulting ideal will not be completely prime:  let $F$ be any field, $R=M_2(F)$ and $a=\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. The resulting maximal ideal disjoint from the powers of $a$ is $\{0\}$, but $\{0\}$ is not a completely prime ideal.
